# Add in routerLink params only if it's not null or undefined?

Tags: angular

How can I add in router link params but only if it's not null or undefined?

Something like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/user/bob']" [queryParams]="{test? test:test : '', test2?test2:test2:''}" queryParamsHandling="merge">
  link to user component
</a>
```

I have multiple values so all of them I need to check if they are not null or undefined to add them in params

Comment: Update your question with exactly what you're trying to accomplish and show us `a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` please.

Comment: i posted example what i want to achive, but i dont know how...  i have multiple values and i want to add them in url but only those that are not null or undefined

Comment: how many possible values are there? does the amount of possible values change or is it static? show us your component.ts

Comment: `[queryParams]="someMethodDoingWhateverYouNeedWithTheFullPowerOfTypeScript()"`?

Comment: @JunKang i have 6 values and their values changes because im getting data from service .

Comment: @JBNizet i can use method for queryParams? what will i return ? string ?

Comment: **Every time** you use [foo]="bar", `bar` is an angular expression. A method call is a valid angular expression. Since queryParams expects an object with keys (the param names) and values (the param values), the method must return such an object. This is fundamental stuff. Read a good book, or the official angular doc.

Comment: What do you pass into `[queryParams]`? an object. What would the method return? an object. configure a queryParams object in your typescript and return it the way @JbNizet mentioned.